# with increasing age vs with age

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I learned from a native speaker that **with increasing age** doesn't mean that the same people are getting older. It means "as the age category increases" and therefore is right for the graph. Is this correct?

What about **with age**? Does it mean that the same people are getting older and therefore is wrong for the graph?

The percentage of students studying for a career fell **with increasing age/with age**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context is everything, and Google is your friend.

A quick search turned up these examples:

- With increasing age, body fat increases and muscle mass reduces.
- Metabolic rate also lowered with increasing age.
- With increasing age maximal HR decreases.

All of these examples are talking about the individual, not an age group. They all mean that, as an average individual's age increases, other things start to decrease, reduce or appear.

An individual's age does increase - one day you're 30, the next day you're 31. But the age groups in your report do not 'increase'. The 26-29 group will always be the 26-29 group. Individuals progress through the age bands as their individual age increases.

If your sole source of data is this chart, you can't really make any observation about the pattern of something with increasing age, so it would be best to say "*the percentage of students studying for a career progressively decreases throughout the age bands*". However, if you as a data analyst have seen the data behind this visual, perhaps because you have created it, and you can support the claim that the metric decreases in line with increasing age, then by all means say "*the percentage studying for a career progressively decreases as age increases*".